# Splitting dataframe based on mixed values in one column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning pandas and I've come upon an obstacle which I can't handle myself.

Let's say I have a list of `cities` but they are ordered by `states` and `names of states` are (unfortunately) *also entries in this list*.

It looks like this:

```
Alabama
Auburn
Florenceville
...
Alaska
Fairbanks
...
```

I have a list of `states`, too. I'm looking for a method to add a new column specifying the state (also to get rid of the state entries - but that one's easy), so that it looks like this:

```
+----------------+--------------+
| City           |  State       |
+----------------+--------------+
| Auburn         |  Alabama     |
| Florenceville  |  Alabama     |
| ...            |  ...         |
| Fairbanks      |  Alaska      |
| ...            |  ...         |
+----------------+--------------+
```

I've loaded them into a `dataframe` and added a column `isstate` which has boolean values. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a quick thought, I guess in your list first you have state then followed by cities in the list. You can get the indices of the states first then using those indices you can get the state name and then cities in that state by the next state index.

Comment: Actually I found a solution :) - I created two new columns ['State', 'City'], filling them with the names from the list according to the 'isstate' col. Then I just used the fillna method to complete the 'State' col and removed the obsolete entries. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Can you please share your solution thought, i am just interested to know how you solved it.

Comment: Here's the code: 

data['state'] = data['name'].where(data['isstate'] == True).fillna(method="ffill")
    data['city'] = data['name'].where(data['isstate'] == False)
    data = (data.where(data['isstate'] == False)
            .dropna())